# Targetting a variable and then using CSS Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a variable `$obj` which has `$(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment")` as its value. No I want to use some CSS Selectors on `$obj`. How can I use them?

Selectors I want to use: `:not(:last-child)`.

#### My Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="major_data">
    <div class="commitment_box">
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 1:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 2:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 3:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 4:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.major_data .commitment_box {
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.major_data .commitment_box .commitment p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.major_data .commitment_box .commitment p:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function tick() {
    var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");
    $obj.first().delay(1000).fadeOut(function () {
        $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
        tick();
    });
}
tick();
```

**Result:**
[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vCgQy/)

**My Question:**
I want to target the `:not(:last-child)` of the `$obj`. I know I can do that by simply writing that whole big value of `$obj` but is that possible *only* using the *variable* `$obj`?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: your jsfiddle has error

Comment: @ebramtharwat just saw it! can you solve it? please tell me?

Comment: the error is here **if () $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());**, do u see the empty () after if ? what's yr condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$obj.find(':not(:last-child)')` should work

Answer (score 1):

`$obj.not(':last')` should be your target.

But I don't understand your `if` statement.